# How to copy Big Data from GCS to S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

How to copy a few terabytes of data from GCS to S3?

There's nice "Transfer" feature in GCS that allows to *import* data from S3 to GCS. But how to do the *export*, the other way (besides moving data generation jobs to AWS)?

Q: Why not `gsutil`?
Yes, gsutil supports `s3://`, but transfer is limited by that machine network throughput. How to easier do it in parallel?

I tried Dataflow (aka Apache Beam now), that would work fine, because it's easy to parallelize on like a hundred of nodes, but don't see there's simple 'just copy it from here to there' function.

UPDATE: Also, Beam seems to be computing a list of source files on the local machine in a single thread, before starting the pipeline. In my case that takes around 40 minutes. Would be nice to distribute it on the cloud.

UPDATE 2: So far I'm inclined to use two own scripts that would:

- Script A: Lists all objects to transfer, and enqueue a transfer task for each one into a PubSub queue.
- Script B: Executes these transfer tasks. Runs on cloud (e.g. Kubernetes), many instances in parallel

The drawback is that it's writing a code that may contain bugs etc, not using a built-in solution like GCS "Transfer".

Answer (score 2):

You could use gsutil running on Compute Engine (or EC2) instances (which may have higher network bandwidth available than your local machine).
Using gsutil -m cp will parallelize copying across objects, but individual objects will still be copied sequentially.

Comment: Thank you, but how to let those multiple GCE instances to process _different_ sets of objects? If I just run `gsutil -m cp` they all will be copying same files. Maybe `gsutil -m rsync` is race-free (I doubt it, as it first builds a list of objects to sync), but thoe N GCE instances will still be checking/transferring same object N times.

Comment: You could shard copies across multiple instances using something like:
gsutil -m cp gs://your-bucket/a* s3://your-bucket
gsutil -m cp gs://your-bucket/b* s3://your-bucket
etc.

where you run each command on a separate instance. The above assumes your object names are distributed roughly uniformly by English alphabet first letter. If not you may need to adjust the commands.